# Aroon Indicator in PySpark: How to count the number of rows between the max value and the current value in each group

Tags: python, pyspark, quantitative-finance, technical-indicator

## Arron Up, Aroon Dn, Aroon Oscillator

def myFunction(myData):

```
df = myData

col = 'Date'
groupCols = ['Name']
window=Window.partitionBy(groupCols).orderBy(df[col].asc()).rowsBetween(-11, 0)

max_value = max(df['value']).over(window)
min_value = min(df['value']).over(window)

df = df.withColumn('max', max_value)
df = df.withColumn('min', min_value)
```

## I need to find the number of rows between the max value and the current value for each group

```
periods_since_max = 
periods_since_min = 

df = df.withColumn('periods_since_max', periods_since_max)
df = df.withColumn('periods_since_min', periods_since_min)

aroon_up = ((12.0 - df['periods_since_max'])/12.0) * 100
aroon_dn = ((12.0 - df['periods_since_min'])/12.0) * 100

df = df.withColumn('aroon_up', aroon_up)
df = df.withColumn('aroon_dn', aroon_dn)
 
oscillator = df['aroon_up'] - df['aroon_dn']
df = df.withColumn('oscillator', oscillator)

return df
```

Comment: Please post a sample from myData

Comment: I cannot share the data, but I am basically trying to run Aroon Indicator on grouped data. I have 3 columns: Name, Date and Value. Need to group by Name, sort by Date and find the number of rows between the max Value (for the last 12 months) and the current Value within each group. That is, the number of periods since max for each value in the Value column grouped by Name.